# prepare-commit-msg test the output for different scenarios

Tags: git, githooks, git-commit

I made a prepare-commit-msg hook that will add a lot of data to the commit message that will be presented to my developers.

I want to test the output of the prepare-commit-msg hook automatically so i can use jenkins to validate if the new changes i made is messing up the old format.

But how do i "trigger" and get the output from the prepare-commit-msg hook without git opens op an editor.

is there a workaround.

git commit -m "Text" 
Does not give me the output anywhere or maybe it does ?

or should i really add this testing internally in the hook so when i enable debugging i should get the output ?

I would just prefer git could give me the output instead as it is the message that will be presented to the developer.